# How to refresh child component from parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have a page that allows the user to upload and display a photo.  The backend API is all built out.  My problem is after I successfully upload the photo, I need to refresh the page in order to see the new photo at the bottom of the page.  Here's the relevant code:

**Parent Component**

```
refreshPage = (value) =>  {

    if(this.state.photoUploaded)
    {
        //this refreshes the API call to get the new photo
        this.componentDidMount();
    }    
};

async componentDidMount(){
    const url = <the url of my API>;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({eventdata:data});

    var i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < data.photos.length; i++)
    {
       this.state.photos.push({"url":data.photos[i].url});
    }
    this.setState({loading:false});
}

render(){
    <div>
        <PhotoSelectorComponent eventdata={this.state.eventdata} refreshPage={this.refreshPage}></PhotoSelectorComponent>
        <PhotoDisplayComponent photos={this.state.photos} eventdata={this.state.eventdata} refreshPage={this.refreshPage}></PhotoDisplayComponent>
    </div>
}
```

I have the PhotoSelectorComponent notifying the Parent Component when a Photo has been uploaded.  It calls the RefreshPage function, which calls componentDidMount(), which makes the api call an additional time, and I see the new photo in my photos array.  I'm not even sure if this is the best way to do this, but it's an idea that I tried based on what I've read, and it's working.  But I'm not sure how to re-render the PhotoDisplayComponent at this point.  I'm updating the state, but it's not refreshing the page.  I'm very close to making this work, but I'm not sure if they way that I have it setup currently is best practice or not.  I feel like the page should just refresh itself if I have everything wired correctly.

Comment: Possibly the solution can involve componentWillReceiveProps?

Answer (score 0):

You have some basic React mistakes there, like directly mutating state and calling setState few times in the same function. Try this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'someurl';
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();   

    const newPhotos = data.photos.map((photo) => {
      return { "url": photo.url }
    })


    this.setState(({
      loading: false,
      photos:[...this.state.photos,...newPhotos],//I dont think you actually get only new photos, but following your code...
      eventdata: data
    }));
  }
```

Also i think your architecture doesn't make much sense, because i've never seen a direct call to componentDidMount.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately, that has the same issues.

Comment: Please upload your entire working code to github or some playground, i'll take a look.

Comment: One of my teammates fixed the issue.  It was an issue with "this.props".  He removed the "this" and it started working.  I can't explain why, but it worked.  Thanks @i.brod for the offer to help!